# RestKit and Chunked transfer encoding

Tags: ios, restkit, chunked-encoding

Does RestKit support [Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)? Looks like it doesn't, but maybe I miss something.

If I have the following header for the response, which I receive:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
.....
```

and the response looks like:

```
2289
{ "firstParam": "firstValue", "secondParam":"secondValue"}
0
```

Is it any way to use RestKit to map this json in the response to my objects automatically? If not, what can I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

RestKit offers a few options for interacting with the requests that are actually going to be sent. For example, you could use `requestWithObject:method:path:parameters:` to get an `NSMutableURLRequest` and set the headers you want. Then use `objectRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` (or the managed object equivalent) to generate the operation that can be run to execute the request.

Comment: sorry.. I can't understand how your answer is connected with my question.

Comment: Just re-read your question. I thought you meant send a chunked request and receive a response. Have you tried receiving a chunked response? It should be handled transparently by NSURLConnection (you should know nothing about it)...

Comment: yeah, I need to receive a chunked response. I tried to do this. but RestKit can't understand this format.

Comment: Presumably your response data actually fits into one chunk. In some cases it won't? `NSURLConnection` does seem to work with chunked. The response you show isn't valid JSON so RestKit won't like that...

Comment: yes, it's not a valid JSON. that's the problem. but it looks like it's a valid response for Chunked transfer encoding. have no idea how many chunks I can have.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it put the chunk size in the header, but no. Do you have any option to change the server? Currently you would need to modify the AFNetworking code to handle this.

Comment: the problem is that the server code is not under our control. we asked to remove this for now, but the services developers what to put it back in the future. so.. I'll need to resolve it somehow. and now it looks like it'll take quite a lot of time. hope I just miss some simple solution

Comment: anyway @Wain thanks for your try to help! at least I had discussed it with you.